# How to overcome the IllegalAccessError while start up of connector in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am writing a connector for Kafka Connect. The error I see during the start up of connector is

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigTransformer.DEFAULT_PATTERN from class org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder
```

The error seems to happen at https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/AbstractHerder.java#L449

Do I need to set this `DEFAULT.PATTERN` manually? Is this not set by default.

I am using the docker image confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.1. The version of connect-api I am using in my connector app is org.apache.kafka:connect-api:2.0.0. I am running my set up inside Kubernetes.

Comment: Not that it matters, but Confluent 5.0.1 would be running Kafka 2.0.1 APIs

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved when I changed the image to confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.0-2.

I already tried this option before posting the question, but the pod was in a Pending state and was refusing to start. I thought that it could have been an issue with the image. Upon doing some more research later, I came to know that sometimes Kubernetes is unable to allot enough resources and hence pods can stay in Pending state.

I tried the image confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.0-2 and it works fine.

Comment: Just to add to the information here, if you are using confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base image, using version 5.0.0-1 solved this issue for me.